# C++ - Using Bag of Words for matching pictures together?

Tags: c++, opencv, matching, sift

I would like to compare a picture (with his descriptors) with thousand of pictures inside a database in order to do a matching. (if two pictures are the same,that is to say the same thing but it can bo rotated, a bit blured, has a different scale etc.).

For example :
[image]

I saw on StackOverflaw that compute descriptors for each picture and compare them one to one is very a long process.
I did some researches and i saw that i can do an algorithm based on Bag of Words.

I don't know exactly how is works yet, but it seems to be good. But in think, i can be mistaked, it is only to detect what kind of object is it not ?

I would like to know according to you if using it can be a good solution to compare a picture to a thousands of pictures using descriptors like [Sift](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scale-invariant_feature_transform) of Surf ?

If yes, do you have some suggestions about how i can do that ?

Thank,

Comment: if you're curious about BOW, [read a bit](http://gilscvblog.wordpress.com/2013/08/23/bag-of-words-models-for-visual-categorization/). but again, for finding duplicates in a database, other approaches, like [phash](http://www.phash.org/) might be better, faster, and easier to use

Comment: i already read this document about BoW but justly, i wonder if it can be a good way to find the same image in an database using it because i have the impression, it is only to detect and categorize objects, no ?

Comment: What you say "if two pictures are the same" what do you mean by "same?"  Pixel-for-pixel identical?  Identical modulo compression artifacts?  Scaling?  Rotation?  Two images of one apple taken at different times?  Two images of two different apples?

Comment: yes, classifying is the main use of it. and the features/desscriptors approach is good at finding things in images, not so much at general similarity. btw, maybe be a bit more explicit, on what 'matching', or 'same' means in your context ? would a scaled instance count as same ? grayscale or cropped ? are you looking for content ? (picture of eiffel tower)

Comment: yeah sorry,i've edited my post. The same for me, means the same picture but it can be rotated,bit blurred, has a different scale etc. I've implemented sift with a robust matcher and it works well. no i want to do the same but inside a database of thousands picture if possible...

Comment: Yes, BoW is exactly for this job, among others. Read a bit more [here](http://web.cs.swarthmore.edu/~turnbull/cs97/f08/paper/sivic03.pdf) and [here](http://www.robots.ox.ac.uk:5000/~vgg/publications/2007/Philbin07/philbin07.pdf) and [here](http://image.ntua.gr/iva/files/hpm_iccv11a.pdf). Check the demo [here](http://viral.image.ntua.gr/), working on more than 2 million images.

Comment: Okey i'll read thoses papers and try to implement the algorithm ! thank

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. The only thing you have to pay attention is the computational requirement which can be a little overwhelming. If you can narrow the search, that usually help.

To support my answer I will extract some examples from a recent work of ours. We aimed at recognizing a painting on a museum's wall using SIFT + RANSAC matching. We have a database of all the paintings in the museum and a SIFT descriptor for each one of them. We aim at recognizing the paining in a video which can be recorded from a different perspective (all the templates are frontal) or under different lighting conditions. This image should give you an idea: on the left you can see the template and the current frame. The second image is the SIFT matching and the third shows the results after RANSAC.

[image]

Once you have the matching between your image and each SIFT descriptor in your database, you can compute the reprojection error, namely the ratio between matched points (after RANSAC) and the total number of keypoints. This can be repeated for each image and the image with the lowest reprojection error can be declared as the match.

We used this for paintings but I think that can be generalized for every kind of image (the android logo you posted in the question is a fair example i think).

Hope this helps!

Comment: it seems great ! So you don't use BoW ?
But painting on a museums represent a lot of data no ? About Hundreds ? How about the process ? Is it long, effective ?
So if i understand well, you record all the painting in a database with their descriptors (not keypoints ?) and after you make a comparison between the painting you want and the frame in the video ?
Thank you !

Comment: It is a quite expensive process, computationally speaking. We apply techniques in order to reduce the search range (e.g. if you locate a painting, assume that the next will be in the same room or in a close one, effectively pruning the search a lot). If you can apply some sort of assumption, it will help a lot.
In terms of accuracy using SIFT we achieve 0.158 FAR and 0.430 FRR..it's pretty neat for a research project, not sure about real applications. And yes, we store in our db descriptors not keypoint.